# Why prepopulated database is not working in active Android

Tags: android, database

I have made an application using [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/) database library and it is working fine.

As I have to insert a large amount of data, I want to use a pre-populated database which will be placed in the asset folder. According to the [ActiveAndroid pre-populated database documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Pre-populated-databases), I have created a meta table and put the database in the asset folder.

When I am going to retrieve data using the model, my application is showing no data in the table. What can I do now?

Comment: copy the database to SDCard/internal memory on first load, then access it from there.

Comment: any error , exception or warning ?

Comment: I am checking the size of the returned data. But the size is 0

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ?